# Does clang apply options by default?

Tags: clang

For example, when compiling a simple program

`clang hello_world.c`

Does the clang add any options by default? Like link library, include search path or optimization flags -O0 or exploit-mitigation flags like -mlvi-cfi?

If so, how to get a full list of default options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Clang has default options. The document is [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)